# Lodash object by Index

Tags: javascript, lodash

In lodash,  how can I get an object from an array by the index at which it occurs, instead of searching for a key value.

```
var tv = [{id:1},{id:2}]
var data = //Desired result needs to be {id:2}
```

Comment: why do you need lodash if you know the index?

Comment: In ES2015 there is a built-in [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for that: `const data = tv.find(i => i.id == 2);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To directly answer your question about retrieving an object from an array using its index in lodash:

Given your array:

```js
var tv = [{id:1},{id:2}];
```

You can simply use:

```js
var data = tv[1]; // This will give you the desired result: {id:2}
```

This is a basic JavaScript operation, and you don't really need lodash for this specific task.

However, if you're interested in other ways to fetch items from a collection based on their attributes, I'd like to share a couple of lodash techniques:

1. **Using find method** (similar to the Meeseeks solution):

```js
var collection = [{id: 1, name: "Lorem"}, {id: 2, name: "Ipsum"}];
var item = _.find(collection, {id: 2});
console.log(item); // Outputs: Object {id: 2, name: "Ipsum"}
```

1. **Indexing using groupBy** (useful when you want to quickly look up objects by attributes multiple times):

```js
var byId = _.groupBy(collection, 'id');
console.log(byId[2]); // Outputs: Object {id: 2, name: "Ipsum"}
```

But again, if you're simply wanting to get an item from an array based on its position, using the direct array indexing (like `tv[1]`) it's the simplest approach.

Hope this clears things up!

Comment: This example is not correct. The `groupBy` returns an object indexing the collection by the given attribute, where each attribute of this object is an array of the objects matching.

Comment: @xjunior, thank you for pointing it out. I've updated my answer to provide a more direct solution to the original question, and also included additional lodash techniques for broader context. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [`find`](https://lodash.com/docs#find)

You can give it an object and it will return the matched element or `undefined`

Example

```
var arr = [ { id: 1, name: "Hello" }, { id: 2, name: "World" } ];

var data = _.find(arr, { id: 1 }); // => Object {id: 1, name: "Hello"}

var data = _.find(arr, { id: 3 }); // => undefined
```